# How to determine which Browser Certs to reenable on a per-case basis?

Tags: certificates, firefox

Considering that there is no way to [actually see which certs that I use](https://superuser.com/questions/818065/how-to-know-which-certificates-to-leave-in-my-browser-and-which-to-remove) in my regularly-visited websites, I've decided to disable all certs and re-enable them on a case by case basis. This is for the dual goal of **increasing security** and also to **familiarize myself with which CAs to trust**. If [China Internet Network Information Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Internet_Network_Information_Center) is suddenly signing my certificate chain down to Gmail, I would like to know! **Firefox as shipped by Ubuntu does in fact come with that CNNIC cert preinstalled.**

Now that I've disabled all the CAs, when I try to connect to `https://example.com` Firefox correctly informs me that the connection is untrusted. However, I see no way to look at the cert to determine which CA to reenable. When certs are enabled one can click the Firefox [Lock Icon](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-tell-if-my-connection-is-secure) and see the cert, but with the CA used by the cert disabled there seems to way to see the cert. I'm sure that I could script Python and Curl to [reveal the cert details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166359/how-to-grep-the-output-of-curl) but I would prefer something from within Firefox itself. **Does Firefox has a way to show to the user certs that do no have a corresponding CA enabled?** It seems like a glaring oversight if it doesn't.

In the following screenshot it can be seen that the `I Understand the Risks` section to open the Certificate Viewer is not available for certs whose root CA is disabled:

[image]

**TLDR:** How to see the name of the root CA (which I need to re-enable) of a cert that Firefox does not recognize, from within Firefox itself?

Comment: "I Understand" is NOT unavailable because the root is not in the store; as the dialog says, it is unavailable because the particular site (wikipedia) is configured for HSTS, see https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mozilla/security/manager/ssl/nsSTSPreloadList.inc . Your approach will only work on sites that aren't known to use HSTS.

Comment: `curl -v` shows issuer for the server/leaf cert but in practice today that is almost never the root. For OpenSSL and Java, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244751/get-complete-certificate-chain-including-the-root-certificate .

Comment: There are some suggestions in the answers to [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/661978/displaying-a-remote-ssl-certificate-details-using-cli-tools) that allow you to check from the command line. Perhaps, this would help prior to checking in the browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## AIA chasing?

> TLDR: How to see the root CA of a cert that Firefox does not recognize, from within Firefox itself?

You don't directly get to see the root CA. But you may be able to see the immediately superior CA.

Some certificates (all?) have an *Authority Information Access* field that allows a certificate to answer the *Who's your daddy?* question.

(To get to the *Certificate Viewer* window navigate like this:
`I Understand the Risks | Add Exception... | View... | Details`)

[image: Screenshot of AIA field in Firefox Certificate Viewer]

In the case of `example.com` it's this: http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.crt

## Top 15 Root CAs to get you started

Here's the [top 15 root CAs from a scan of the Alexa Top 1 Million (2015-10 by Hubert Kario):](https://securitypitfalls.wordpress.com/2015/11/29/october-2015-scan-results/)

```
Root CAs                                      Count     Percent
---------------------------------------------+---------+-------
(d6325660) COMODO RSA Certification Authority 113492    20.662
(2c543cd1) GeoTrust Global CA                 107601    19.5895
(eed8c118) COMODO ECC Certification Authority 48977     8.9166
(cbf06781) Go Daddy Root Certificate Authorit 47939     8.7276
(5ad8a5d6) GlobalSign Root CA                 44123     8.0329
(b204d74a) VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Ce 29359     5.345
(244b5494) DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA 25999     4.7333
(2e4eed3c) thawte Primary Root CA             23372     4.255
(157753a5) AddTrust External CA Root          20188     3.6754
(653b494a) Baltimore CyberTrust Root          12053     2.1943
(ae8153b9) StartCom Certification Authority   9139      1.6638
(fc5a8f99) USERTrust RSA Certification Author 8775      1.5975
(3513523f) DigiCert Global Root CA            8281      1.5076
(4bfab552) Starfield Root Certificate Authori 8226      1.4976
(480720ec) GeoTrust Primary Certification Aut 5570      1.0141
```

## Miscellaneous

### Certificate Patrol Addon?

Have you tried the Firefox [Certificate Patrol](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/certificate-patrol/) addon? Seems up your alley.

## EDIT2015-12-03: Why does this not work for Wikipedia? HSTS!

I guess this does not work for Wikipedia, because [`wikipedia.org`is HSTS preloaded in Firefox](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/http/transport_security_state_static.json#3351) (archived [here](https://archive.is/999c9#selection-466581.0-466695.2)).

And the *"I understand the Risks"* button is missing because [for HSTS errors a *"no user recourse"* rule is enforced. This is by design.](https://projects.dm.id.lv/Public-Key-Pins_test)

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that the Certificate Viewer is _not_ available for certs whose root CA is disabled, that is the whole premise of the issue. I'll make that clearer in the OP. Thanks.

Comment: @dotancohen: Try this: `I Understand the Risks | Add Exception... | View... | Details` -- This works for me on [https://www.cacert.org/](https://www.cacert.org/) and I don't have their root CA trusted.

Comment: The `I Understand the Risks` button is absent when the root cert is disabled. I'll make that explicit in the OP. Thank you.

Comment: @dotancohen Note that the "I Understand the Risks" is not a button but a section that you can expand. I have verified in Firefox 42 and it is still avaialbe for disabled CAs.

Comment: Right, I'm familiar with the section as I see it often enough fixing botched Apache configurations! It certainly is not present on my Firefox 42.0 on Kubuntu 15.10 when disabling the site's root cert. I'll add a screenshot. Thank you.

Comment: @dotancohen: No luck for HSTS preload sites. See update to my answer.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I did not know of HSTS. Interestingly, the other site that I tested on, Gmail, also is HSTS preloaded.